# Where does the "@logger" service come from in a Symfony application?

Tags: php, symfony, logging, service

My `app/config/services.yml`:

```
services:
  FooService:
    class: path/to/FooService.php
    arguments: [..., "@logger"]
```

My `FooService.php`:

```
class FooService
{
    public function __construct(..., $logger) {
        // $logger here satisfies \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
    }
    ...
}
```

I don't understand where that `LoggerInterface` instance which is passed in as the `$logger` parameter actually *comes from*. The Symfony documentation says (substituting my example names):

> In YAML, the special `@logger` syntax tells the container to look for a service named `logger` and to pass that object into the constructor of `FooService`. In this case, however, the specified service `logger` must exist. If it does not, an exception will be thrown.

Obviously the `logger` service *does* exist, because no exception is thrown and I get an object as the `$logger` parameter. But where does it come from? In all the examples in the documentation, and in my application, this syntax appears to refer to another service defined in `services.yml`. There must be somewhere else that services are defined, but the documentation doesn't say where. Any clues?

Comment: It can be defined in a bundle you have registered in your kernel. Those can have custom services.yml files as well

Comment: There are a bunch of services pre defined by Symfony in the bundles (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Bundle). To view all of the registered services you can use `app/console container:debug`.

Answer (score 1):

vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/MonologBundle/Resources/config/monolog.xml

Note that logger is actually an alias of monolog.logger.  You could write your own logger bundle as a replacement for the monolog bundle.

One way to track down these sorts of things is to search for DependencyInjection\Configuration.php files for parameter collections such as "monolog".